# Replacing the "Hold Tight" Screen on Project Tango for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I was wondering how I would go about changing the "Hold Tight" screen for Google's Project Tango on Unity3D? I was looking at the TangoUx script and it said, "customization of the UX library can be done in the Unity editor or by programmatically setting the member flags." Is it meaning the member variables of the script or the actual images? Also, from what I can tell I would have to make my own image appear on the function OnTangoServiceConnected but when would I make it inactive?

Thank you!

Comment: This is currently not possible through the Unity API, you can listen to the onTangoServiceConnected callback, and display UI through the app layer. We are making some changes to the UX library that may enable this feature.